# Resetting a macro counter to 0

Tags: macros, counters

I have a macro that is disabled after one use.  The worksheet works fine until I need to clean the entire sheet and reuse it the next week.  How do I reset the macro counter to zero so that I can use the macro again?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) We like to avoid greetings or signatures in post to keep them short. They are implied anyway. I'm not sure what you exactly mean with "clean the entire sheet" etc. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: `\setcounter{countername}{0}` would work? BTW, follow the Martin's suggestions

Comment: @Spike: That sure sounds like an answer to me. Not sure why there is a vote to close as "off-topic" as it seems to be very much TeX related.

Comment: @PeterGrill I was waiting for the MWE, to be sure that I didn't misunderstood the question. Do you think that I should transform the comment in a question right now?

Comment: Probably it's just me, but neither do I understand the situation described nor what's being asked...

Comment: Thank you Spike and Peter.  I will try that and see if that works.

Comment: This is my code:
Private codeRun As Boolean

Public Sub CountMacro()
If codeRun Then
Exit Sub
End If
codeRun = True
so basically this particular macro can only be used once during the week.  At the end of the week, the workbook is cleaned of it's data (this is a balance sheet so I need the closing data to be used as opening data each week) and reused the following week.  However, since this macro has now been deactivated, it does not work.  I need to create another macro that when the workbook is cleaned, it also resets the counter for Public Sub CountMacro() to zero so that I can reuse it.